# Android Kotlin - check if type can be casted

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val holder: MemesAdapter.ViewHolder? = binding.contentMain.recyclerViewMemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as MemesAdapter.ViewHolder?
```

Sometimes it can't be casted, it would be workaround to prevent the crash so is there a way to check it beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to check types before casting them

Option 1: using `is`

```
val holder = binding.contentMain.recyclerViewMemes
    .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)

if (holder is MemesAdapter.ViewHolder) {
    // cast is possible, and you don't need to cast it manually
    // because Kotlin smart-cast will do it for you
    // holder is already of type MemesAdapter.ViewHolder inside this if
    holder.someProperty = ...
}
```

Option 2: using `as?` (with the question mark)

```
val holder = binding.contentMain.recyclerViewMemes
    .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as? MemesAdapter.ViewHolder

if (holder != null) {
    // cast succeeded and Kotlin smart-cast ensures
    // it is of type MemesAdapter.ViewHolder (not null!) inside this if
    holder.someProperty = ...
}
```

The first option (using `is`) has the advantage if you have to check for more than just one type (in heterogenous adapters), for example

```
val holder = binding.contentMain.recyclerViewMemes
    .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)

if (holder is MemesAdapter.HeaderViewHolder) {
    holder.someHeaderProperty = ...
} else if (holder is MemesAdapter.ItemViewHolder) {
    holder.someItemProperty = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this before casting with `as` keyword

```
if (holder is MemesAdapter.ViewHolder)
```

`is` is crucial in here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `as?` instead of `as` to either get the casted value, or null, if casting is unsuccessful.